# ImageMap control not changing

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagemap

I try to set my ImageMap control to diffrent imageurl like this:

```
ImageMap1.ImageUrl = grapth;
Response.Redirect("~/StockData.aspx");
```

But for some reason the page ImageMap ImageUrl stays the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Response.Redirect`, the browser will issue an entirely new HTTP request, and all state (such as `ImageMap1.ImageUrl`) associated with the current page is discarded.

If the current page is already StockData.aspx, then you should simply remove the redirect.